# Deeplink is not opening in samsung default browser

Tags: android, react-native, samsung-internet

We are devoloping an ecommerce app using react native, we want to make it possible to open our app from samsung default browser(now the policy of samsung browser is to prohibit deeplinking and links that opens other apps) Can any body help or have a solutions for this issue please.

we used “intent://” scheme but  it is not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.